# How to test WML script program?

Tags: testing, wml

Can we test WML scripts on the PC? Is there any emulator for testing it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wmlbrowser) for viewing WML pages, if that's the WML you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I Think [Opera mobile emulator](http://in.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/) was good for this.
I've been using it to test our product before we test it again on actual devices